# How can I change my method to achive the following?

Tags: linq, lambda, iqueryable

I have this method that is supposed to search collection of Employees by names.
I pass the array of last names I want to find, and the method returns Employees with these names. Simple.

```
    public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(IEnumerable<string> lastNames)
    {
        var query = Employees.Where(e => lastNames.Contains(e.LastName));
        return query;
    }
```

Now I need to change the method so that I can pass array of **partial** lastnames, and get all Employees whose last names match the partial last names.

```
    public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(IEnumerable<string> partialLastNames)
    {
        // the code above will not work
    }
```

So that If I have employees with these names: 
Sigourney Weaver, Amanada Beaver, John Smith, Jane Matheson

And I pass partialLastName arary ["aver", "math"], it will return me  a query that will match: Sigourney Weaver, Amanada Beaver and Jane Matheson

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(IEnumerable<string> partialLastNames)
{
      var query = Employees.Where(e => partialLastNames.Any(x => e.LastName.Contains(x)));
      return query;
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to worry about mixed case matches as they are looking for?

Comment: Great! Thank you very much !!
Actually in original function I need to do search by partial Employee Number (digits). So I will be fine. Thanks.

Comment: Although this approach works, but only up to a certain length of partialLastNames. Approximately 48-49 elements in arrays. When I pass 50 strings, I get exception thrown: 
Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

I believe, because the SQL query created by this LINQ expression using UNION for each string and reaches the maximum nesting level for SQL query. 

Need another approach...

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver - I recommend opening up a new question,